# How i can make a consumption bar in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

how i can make a consumption bar?
I tried using seekbar but its not the expected result so whats the best way to do it?
Im adding an image where this bar show up as example
im using eclipse and android sdk plugin

[image: consumption Bars]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `ProgressBar`.

[ProgressBar Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)

Comment: actually this is what i want "horizontal" progress bar, i need how to make a "arrow" showing the current level, any idea? thanks:)